# SciPy gaussian_kde density plots are incorrect

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to plot a probability distribution that has been calculated through Monte Carlo runs. I am using sp.stats.gaussian_kde() to determine the point densities that are used with plt.scatter() to plot the distributions. When I use this block of code for a data det:

```
xy = np.vstack([state_error_x, state_error_y])
error_density_xy = gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)
idxy = error_density_xy.argsort()
xyerror_density_x, xyerror_density_y, xyerror_density_xy = state_error_x[idxy], state_error_y[idxy], error_density_xy[idxy]

plt.figure(7, figsize=(12, 9))

plt.title('State Errors - Position')

plt.subplot(221)
plt.scatter(xyerror_density_x, xyerror_density_y, c=xyerror_density_xy, edgecolor='')
plt.xlabel('X ($m$)')
plt.ylabel('Y ($m$)')
plt.axis('equal')
```

Repeated for each distribution, I end up with the following plot:

[image]

This looks correct. But when I do the same thing with a different distribution, using this code:

```
rtn_xy = np.vstack([state_error_rtn_x, state_error_rtn_y])
rtn_error_density_xy = gaussian_kde(rtn_xy)(rtn_xy)
rtn_idxy = rtn_error_density_xy.argsort()
rtn_xyerror_density_x, rtn_xyerror_density_y, rtn_xyerror_density_xy = state_error_x[rtn_idxy], state_error_y[rtn_idxy], rtn_error_density_xy[rtn_idxy]

plt.figure(9, figsize=(12, 9))

plt.title('State Errors - Position')

plt.subplot(221)
plt.scatter(rtn_xyerror_density_x, rtn_xyerror_density_y, c=rtn_xyerror_density_xy, edgecolor='')
plt.xlabel('R ($m$)')
plt.ylabel('T ($m$)')
plt.axis('equal')
```

I end up with the following plot:

[image]

The second set of plots do not have a clear dispersion of density here and show very dense points in areas where they are not closely surrounded by many points and show non-dense points in dense areas. Granted not many of these densities are wrong but its noticeable enough and definitely changes the overall result in a negative way.

Any thoughts on how to fix this issue? Thanks for any help.